# Ruby Chinese character substring difficulties

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, substring, cjk

For my rails site, there's some UI with only enough space to display the first 5 characters of a user's name. So I'm truncating the string to display as follows:

```
@user.name[0..4]
```

It works if the name is in English. But if `@user.name` contains Chinese (multibyte) characters, two problems arise. The first problem is that `[0..4]` only gives me 2 characters, not 5. The second  problem is that sometimes the last character gets cut in half and garbage shows up on screen.

I was wondering if there's some relatively clean way to handle substring-ing multibyte characters in ruby?

Comment: Which Ruby version? Multibyte support was added in 1.9.

Comment: Yes I would strongly recommend ruby 1.9 if you are doing anything with multibyte, the support in 1.8x is not good.

Comment: I'm using ruby 1.8.7, upgrading is a bit painful, is there some way to manually make it happen in 1.8x?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here's](http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/bytes_and_characters_in_ruby_18) an excellent article about Ruby 1.8 and multibyte support (or, rather, the lack of it).

Based on what's there, you can try doing something like:

```
# this should get you first 4 characters of the string:
your_chinese_string.scan(/./mu)[0,4].join
```

Comment: I've confirmed that this solution works. I'm a bit confused about why it works. So the scan(/./mu) parts of it puts UTF8 characters into an array? Thank you very much nevertheless!